Deploying Vercel Python app, but still returning 404 error
Trying to deploy my application to Vercel, but its giving a

404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND

Here is my vercel.json:
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "./api/index.py",
            "use": "@vercel/python"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/api/(.*)",
            "dest": "/"
        }
    ]
}

Here is my directory:
api\ index.py vercel.json requirements.txt
Here is my index.py:
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Here is some information'

This is my requirements.txt:
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
google-pasta==0.1.7
python-dotenv==0.20.0
requests==2.22.0
virtualenv==20.4.2
virtualenv-clone==0.5.4
vonage==2.5.5

P.S. I know there's extra libraries here right now that are not needed currently.
Tried deploying on vercel to production by pushing to main, deployed successfully, but not able to access anything.
